# About JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("sel");
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    opt = new Option(names[i]); 
    selectElement.options.add(opt);
}
```

I do not understand the meaning of this code " selectElement.options.add(opt);"
could somebody please explain for me, thanks!

Comment: Take the select element, get the list of options from it, then add a new one. That's it.

Comment: It adds names/options into your dropdown list so that you can select.

Comment: `selectElement.options.add(opt);` doesn't seem valid. `selectElement.add(opt);` would be and is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add *edit:* I guess `options.add` does actually exist, but may be missing from the MDN documentation. Nevertheless I suspect it's the same as `select.add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what each component of your code does:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("sel");
```

This makes a variable `selectElement` which represents the element with ID `sel`.

```
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
```

Makes a variable `i` which is looped over for each element in the array `names`.

```
opt = new Option(names[i]);
```

Sets `opt` to an option created with the index in the array `names` current iteration of `i`.

```
selectElement.options.add(opt);
```

Adds `opt` to the list of options in the `selectElement` variable.

```
}
```

Ends the for loop